# retrieve unread messages as model method eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, message

I have a simple messaging system, the works like this,

1 user can own many conversations
1 user can be in receipt of many conversations
1 conversation has many messages

The table structure looks like this,

**Coversation**.

ID |
title |
created_by (user) |
recipient (user) |
created_at |
updated_at |

**Messages**.

ID | content | conversation_id | sent_by | read_at | created_at | updated_at

What I am wanting to achieve is to get a count (or collection) all the unread users as relationship/model function, i.e.

```
$user->unreadMessages();
```

Is this possible? I am struggling to work out how to do it, as I cant just query the messages, I need only the messages for conversations that I the user is involved in but they have not sent.

Hope some can help. I am utterly confused, maybe database needs some redesigning to aid read receipts?

Comment: "all the unread users " whaaat?

Comment: check "hasManyThrough" on the documentation

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments use the `hasManyThrough` which provides access to distant relations via an intermediate relation.

Define relationships as follow:

User Model

```
 /**
 * Get all of the UnReadMessages of the user.
 */
public function unreadMessages()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
                  Message::class,
                  Conversation::class,
                  'created_by',
                  'conversation_id')
                  ->whereNull('read_at');
}
```